# Sendind Ajax request, response in Json or html format to browser(which one is efficient)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

In my project i use Ajax and get response from server.Now I have two option

a) At server create Html from the data and sends to browser

b) Directly sends data at browser in Json Format and create Html at browser.

which one is more efficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no significant difference. JSON could be a little slower because it has to encode the data from an array, but I usually use JSON because I often send extra data with AJAX answers.
On Client side JSON needs to get converted to HTML of course but that doesn't cause much lag.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, server-side rendering will be more efficient (Particularly if the client side is javascript running on a mobile device.)

Comment: Todays mobile devices are not so slow that they aren't able to just create some HTML from JSON.